# Insert new elements at specific index - isotope Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Is there any way I can insert new elements at a specific index, without using sorting? For example, suppose we have a function like this - `isotope('insertAtIndex', elem, 4)`, isotope would insert new element 'elem' at 5th position in layout.

I tried creating my custom function based on 'prepended' function but it just breaks the layout.

```
Isotope.prototype.insertAtIndex = function( elems, index ) {
    var items = this._itemize( elems );
    if ( !items.length ) {
        return;
    }
    // add items to beginning of collection
    var previousItems1 = this.items.slice(0, index);
    var previousItems2 = this.items.slice(index);
    this.items = previousItems1.concat(items).concat(previousItems2);
    // start new layout
    this._resetLayout();
    this._manageStamps();
    // layout new stuff without transition
    var filteredItems = this._filterRevealAdded( items );
    // layout previous items
    this.layoutItems( previousItems1 );
    this.layoutItems( previousItems2 );
    // add to filteredItems
    this.filteredItems = filteredItems.concat( this.filteredItems );
};
```